# Simple game development with WPF or Unity

Tags: c#, wpf, unity-game-engine

WPF provides some amazing features to work with animations. I was wondering if it would be fit for the development of simple games like [Istrolid](http://www.istrolid.com/). I believe WPF can replicate almost (if not all) of the animation in Istrolid. I am good with WPF, but I am yet to start with Unity.

Is WPF better in my case or is it worth investing time in learning Unity for the development of such simple games.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WPF supports both 2D and 3D rendering but it will **only** work on Windows. Unity is multi-platform and will work on more than 10 platforms. If you want to be making games for Windows **only** then use WPF. If you want a game that can be played on iOS, Android, Windows and many more then go with Unity. I would recommend you go with Unity. If you know how to use WPF that means that you are good with C#. You should just jump into Unity.

Comment: Great insight on the cross-platform, i think the more platform, the more audience

Comment: Yes, and mobile games is like the new thing. Making a WPF game will likely be a waste of time since they wont work on a mobile devices. Also, porting that will be a problem too.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, working with both I would run with Unity, but that is more a personal opinion.  The Unity animations are amazing and simple.  Getting used to the interface is a bit tricky, but PLENTY of online tutorials, YouTube and more for simple parts of development to even very complex.  Good luck on your research / development.

Comment: I BELIEVE so.  I just installed the free version of Unity on my son's machine and it recognized and auto-downloaded VS.  It typically uses MonoDeveloper for the IDE/Coding, but you can set configuration settings to use Visual Studio so you get the great other editing within VS that I find better than MonoDeveloper.

Comment: @HishamMaudarbocus Yes there is an [integration](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/VisualStudioIntegration.html) with Unity3D and Visual Studio. I would recommend Unity3D too. Although indeed it's possible to create a game like that with WPF. Unity's game engine is multi purpose, and can be published on multiple platforms. It's definitely worth the investment!

Answer (score 2):

Unity is better for creating games where you want to have the physics, audio and rendering struggle all done. The environment is very user-friendly, the development is smooth and you better know whats going on in the game. But might restrict some of the features.

In WPF, you need to care about a lot of things before you can even start to make a game. But you're pretty much limitless. You have full access to .NET Framework, other libraries and such, you have the full control.

It's a personal preference whenever you enjoy the process of making the game from the very start or you just want to go straight in the game development environment. For simple games, the Unity is usually a better choice.

Also, the platform support isn't much of the question unless you want to make a mobile game (I would go straight to Unity there). 85% of computers use Windows OS, so the platform support isn't such a big deal.

**Edit:** Oh well, you can use .NET libs in Unity as well by importing them into the project - they will be referenced straight. Still, it overall depends on what you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

The real problem that should interest you here is **Engine**.

**Unity** is a ready and cross-platform complete engine with physics and stuff.

In other side:

**WPF** is just .Net Framework and you (well.. and some libraries), so that's up on you to carry on all that stuff (creating physics, renderer, etc..) for making a game.

If you are planning to create some very custom stuff or something easy like tic-tac-toe for windows then go with **WPF**.

But if you want to create some 3D first person space shooter, then personally I would suggest you to use *Unity* or some other (already completed) engine (or if you have a lot of time and creativity, create your own engine).

Comment: I must agree with you and thanks for the reply even if I already got the answer, I hope it helps someone in the future