# C# UI-Design WPF or Unity3D

Tags: c#, wpf, unity-game-engine

I started with WPF and designed my first UI Designs, but I'm not sure, if WPF is good or should I use Unity3d instead of WPF (Expression Blend).

Does somebody has experience with both and give me some recommendation with pro and cons

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple game development with WPF or Unity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38351456/simple-game-development-with-wpf-or-unity)

Comment: Unity and WPF work completely differently internally.  As someone who started with making games in Unity and had to later learn WPF, it was a pain to switch how I think about it, and things that are easy in one are hard in the other.  You should use this question to decide: do you need lots of 2D or 3D graphics, movement, and in general make it act like a game?  Use Unity.  Is it going to sit there and not do much most of the time except for when the user interacts with it?  Use WPF.

Comment: @Cody The most important thing to worry about is platforms supported.

Comment: If platforms is the primary issue, then with WPF you're going to be mostly restricted to new-ish Windows machines, with Unity you can export to nearly any OS.  However, Unity executables have to package a gigantic amount of engine code and assets, making the final install size huge.  If you aren't going to be using those features in a game, it just adds a ton of junk to your product.

Comment: Depends on what you'd like to accomplish.